# What can a DBA do when multiple tables are locked?

Tags: mysql

I have multiple tables `locked` and it seems like they are preventing other queries from running. What could cause this issue and how can I prevent it? What can I do in the meantime to release these `locks`? I read through mysql doc but I don't really understand what the procedure is to preventing this issue.

```
+----------+----------+--------+-------------+
| Database | Table    | In_use | Name_locked |
+----------+----------+--------+-------------+
| bd1      | table1   |      0 |           0 |
| bd1      | table2   |      5 |           0 |
| bd1      | table3   |      0 |           0 |
| bd1      | table4   |      1 |           0 |
| bd1      | table5   |      0 |           0 |
| bd1      | table6   |      2 |           0 |
| bd1      | table7   |      4 |           0 |
+----------+----------+--------+-------------+
```

SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;

```
---TRANSACTION A7DF86B, ACTIVE 10 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 376, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 170083, OS thread handle 0x15a8, query id 1780479 23.20.117.233 Server2 Updating
UPDATE table7 SET EId = 'b457200', LEd = '2013-02-19 16:03:34', ELR = 'y', LU = '2013-02-19 16:03:
34' WHERE (ObKey = '79321fc7b5ac')
```

Comment: Find out what sessions are causing the problem. Kill those sessions. Set up a test environment to try to replicate the situation under controlled conditions. Work out what's causing the locking and fix it.

Comment: How would he find out those sessions?

Comment: is it safe to assume that where ever the query above is coming from is causing the issue?

Comment: It gives the thread and query IDs in question @Nicholas; I would guess the OP already knows how... Dev-Ria, no it's not; it might be but you've posted nowhere near enough information to determine that. It's something that your DBA should be able to tell you. That's why you need to test.

Comment: When diagnosing these problems what should I look for? What are the main causes of `LOCKs`?

Answer (score 0):

well, first of all, you should find the queries that reference these tables and understand how they are being used. Second, you can try using some query hints as a way of increasing concurrency. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html